# How to add style to WebComponents in Angular2

Tags: css, angular, web-component

I have a simple element called `my-element` and I would to have `2em` vertical space between adjacent `my-elements`s. So I add a styling

```
my-element + my-element { margin-top: 2em; }
```

My questions is, will this work? `my-element` is a WebComponent and I have declared it in my Angular2 Component as `ViewEncapsulation.Native` which means that the styling is isolated in the Shadow DOM and can not be changed, or at least not with out applying the `/deep/` selector(?)
Since margin is within the box model for `my-element` I assume that the applying a margin to `my-element` actually shouldn't affect `my-element` at all. That is basically what I am experiencing.

So how do I make my `my-element` allow at least to change `margin` since it doesn't affect the rendering of the containing box?

Comment: Can you show us some relevant code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can style direct children. If `<my-element></my-element>` is in the view of an Angular2 component, then you can just style it from styles added to the Angular2 component.

What you can't is to style the content of `<my-element>` but you can add the style properties of `<my-element>` itself.

With `ViewEncapsulation.Native` there is no `/deep/`. Deep was deprecated in Chrome and never added to other browsers.

With `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default), you can use `/deep/` because Angular2 emulates it.

Comment: `/deep/` has been deprecated now.

Comment: @micronyks deprecated where (Chrome, Angular2)?